# zero-inflated negative binomial in Stata

Tags: stata, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I am trying to run a zero-inflated negative binomial analysis in Stata (`zinb`). My question/problem is this: the model's convergence seems dependent on which and how many variables I include in the "inflate" part of the command. I have seen zero-inflated negative binomial results presented in papers before where the results had the same variables for both parts of the model.

Two questions:

Is including all the same variables in both parts of the estimation allowable with `zinb`?

Why would the model converge with some combinations of variables included in the `inflate` part of the command, but not with other combinations?

Example -- if I run the following code, it does not converge.

`zinb prim_gov_signed distmag dem_num prim_reported_from_comm leadership committee_chair tenure year2008 year2009 year2010 if serve_partial2_num==0, inflate (distmag primary dem_num committee_chair log_expend general_herf)`

However, if I remove `distmag` from the `inflate` part of the code, it converges just fine.

Comment: What is and what is not allowable with `zinb` is off-topic here as software-specific. There is an underlying statistical question about convergence of fitting procedure, but it is, I reckon, difficult or impossible for anyone to answer a question precisely when it hinges on a dataset that we can't access. That applies both to those with access to Stata and those who might wish to experiment with other software.

Comment: I'd expect to see a dataset- or subject-matter specific reason for choosing which variables to enter into the `inflate()` option. Absent that, a project looks like a fishing expedition. Although it is fairly obvious, I'll underline that these models aren't always easy to fit! How many parameters are being estimated here and how many observations do you have (please make both explicit)?

Comment: It's less of a fishing expedition than you might think. Here is some background on the analysis:

Comment: @JimCurry Is the scale of distmag very different from the others? Sometimes that can impede convergence.

Comment: We are trying to predict the impact of a legislative district's magnitude (how many legislators it elects) on the legislative successes/failures of those elected. We expect (and find in other tests) that larger district magnitudes elect less effective and successful legislators (for various reasons).

Comment: The above referenced test is looking to predict the # of bills each legislator was able to get passed into law. The zeros are inflated because about 16% of legislators either never introduced a bill, or did not have any bills that were reported by a committee and so did not have any bills eligible for floor consideration and passage.

Comment: The total number of observation is 541, and the number of zeros in the dependent variable is 149

Comment: I'm not sure specifically what you mean by parameters.

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov -- what do you mean, specifically, by scale? `distmag` holds a value of 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: A parameter is whatever is being estimated and shown as such in the output.

Comment: `zinb prim_gov_signed distmag dem_num prim_reported_from_comm leadership committee_chair tenure year2008 year2009 year2010 if serve_partial2_num==0, inflate (primary dem_num committee_chair log_expend general_herf)`

Comment: [here is the output from that command](http://i.imgur.com/zfI1oxX.png)

Comment: Is this what you need to see?

Comment: It's best to edit the question, not give key detail in comments. I count 17 parameters. That's quite a complicated model and I note that several terms are not significant at conventional levels. Some would advise fitting a much simpler model, but it is hard to be definitive, when you may be under some obligation to include particular predictors. My main concern remains that we can only offer broad comments if the dataset is not provided.

Comment: @JimCurry If that's the actual range, I would not worry. I might try adding the `difficult` maximization option to see if that helps.